# Rest API on executed give error

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, curl

Am trying to add products using a rest API provided by woo commerce but it gives me the below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'WooCommerce REST API client requires the cURL PHP extension.' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library-master\lib\woocommerce-api\class-wc-api-client.php:86 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library-master\example\example.php(11): WC_API_Client->__construct('http://www.woot...', 'ck_xxxxxxx...', 'cs_xxxxxxx...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library-master\lib\woocommerce-api\class-wc-api-client.php on line 86

```
require_once( 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library-master/lib/woocommerce-api.php' );

$options = array(
'ssl_verify'      => false,
);

try {

    $client = new WC_API_Client( 'http://www.example.com/demo/wpinsttalledlocation', 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', $options );


    } catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;

    if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) {

        print_r( $e->get_request() );
        print_r( $e->get_response() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the _cURL PHP extension_ installed?

Comment: no i dint can you help me on that

Comment: Sorry I can't help but a simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=curls+php+extension+windows) should help you.

Comment: it is already installed i have removed the extension in php.ini thought was another process but still same error is showing up

Comment: did you restart your server software?

Comment: sry for late reply yes i did

Comment: You're using wrong signature of `WP_API_Client`. Read [this](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/using-woocommerce-rest-api-orders-endpoint/). And you didn't install cURL

Answer (score 0):

You need install php-curl.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl (or your version php)
```

and then, restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```